# Advantages of query find with :select option during the extraction of objects from the database

Tags: mysql, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

A simple matter. If you need only a few attributes of the model, whether a reasonable approach is to use the **:select** option in method find:

```
@users = User.find (:all, 
                    :select => "username, email, registered_on",
                    :conditions => ["username like?", "A%"])
```

Is it brings any benefit from the speed of a db query?

Answer (score 0):

It certainly speeds up retrieval of data from the database, because less information has to be passed over network. The query itself is faster too.

But if you do this, some properties of your object will be uninitialized (those which you didn't retrieve). This might surprise you one day (if you forget about this).

Comment: And therefore the question of whether faster data extraction from the database is worth that may arise in future issues of this object? How do you think ?

Comment: You should decide for yourself. I personally don't use this feature very often.

Comment: "The query itself is faster too" requires a bit of justification don't you think? If the bytes for each row are stored together then it might even be slower to select just a few columns rather than all of them.

Comment: Well, that's what I was always told by database folks. Agree, though, that this has to be measured and verified (or disproved).